# What would be a good replacement for C++ vector in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I'm working on improving my skills in other languages, coming from using c++ as my primary programming language. My current project is hammering down C#.net, as I have heard it is a good in-between language for one who knows both c++ and VB.net.

Typically when working with an unknown number of elements in c++ I would declare my variable as a vector and just go from there. Vectors don't seem to exist in c#, and in my current program I have been using arraylists instead, but I'm starting to wonder if it's a good habit to use arraylists as I read somewhere that it was a carryover from .net 1.0

Long question short- what is the most commonly used listing type for c#?

Comment: The answer to this will apply to any .NET language (including C++/CLI and F#), there are relatively few per-language datatypes in .NET.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you target pre .NET 2.0 versions, use `ArrayList`

If you target .NET 2.0+ then use generic type `List<T>`

You may need to find replacements for other C++ standard containers, so here is possible mapping of C++ to .NET 2.0+ similar types or equivalents:

```
std::vector - List<T>
std::list - LinkedList<T>
std::map - Dictionary<K, V>
std::set - HashSet<T>
std::multimap - Dictionary<K, List<V>>
```

Comment: I think `std::set` would map more closely to `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: What about the performance of `List<T>` in C#? Is it as good as `std::vector` in C++?!

Comment: @Babak Strictly Object Oriented programming languages can't have containers performing the same way as in C++. C++ allocates a vector in a continuous block of memory(A vector of structures or classes is allocated into a continuous block of memory) while Strictly OO programming languages allocate a continuous block of memory of pointers that point into data allocated randomly in the memory. This is very bad for cache. While vectors in C++ are very cache friendly and help drastically accelerate any operation(even insertions), in strictly OO a pass over a vector hits a lot of cache misses...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you explore the System.Collections namespace, especially the System.Collections.Generics set of objects. The built-in functionality can be strongly typed across the various Lists, Dictionaries and NameValueCollections to provide you with a wide range of capabilities. They are also extendable so if they don't do EXACTLY what you need, you just extend them and add the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That'd be [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), I suppose. `ArrayList` is the non-generic type and—as you correctly observed—a leftover from the .NET 1 times. Starting with .NET 2 you can use Generics and therefore `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `List<T>`. You can find the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).